# How do I create a function to remove special characters in Python for Feature Engineering?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a function to remove special characters from a pandas Data Frame but also pass an argument to retain a character required.

```
def strip_characters(c, req_char = ''):
    spec_chars = ["!",'"',"#","%","&","'","(",")","*","+",",","-",".","/",":",";","<","=",">","?","@","[","\\","]","^","_","`","{","|","}","~","–"]

    new_spec = spec_chars.remove(req_char)
    for char in spec_chars:
        c = c.str.replace(char, ' ')
    return c


df['col'] = df['col'].apply(strip_characters,',')  # passing a comma to retain the character

# df['col'] = ['Dining Room', 'Pre-War', 'Laundry in Building', '&Lobby']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['Dining Room', 'Pre-War', 'Laundry in Building', '&Lobby']})

# ([^) means match anything but word character
# "[^\w+|,]" to exclude specific character's from being replaced

df['col'].str.replace("[^\w+]"," ")
```

Ouput

```
0            Dining Room
1                Pre War
2    Laundry in Building
3                  Lobby
```

Comment: Thanks Thats great and if I need to keep , commas ??